# Search that distinguishes the first letters and not the entire character with SearchBar in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string

I have an array of characters and when I search and enter "Co" for example, I get two matches (I don't want that). I want only what begins with a specific character to be searched.

I share the array of strings and the method textDidChange in Swift

For example:

```
listEmployed = ["Conejo","Tetera","Aviteon","Sacoja"]
    
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    isSearching = true
    arrayFilterEmployed = listEmployed
    if searchText.isEmpty == false {
        arrayFilterEmployed = listEmployed?.filter({$0.text.lowercased().range(of: searchText.lowercased(), options: .caseInsensitive) != nil})
    }
    
    if arrayFilterEmployed?.count == 0 {
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
        fountLabel?.isHidden = false
    }
    else {
        categoryTableView?.reloadData()
        fountLabel?.isHidden = true
    }
    categoryTableView?.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add the `.anchored` option. And since you are using `.caseInsensitive`, you don't need the calls to `lowercased()`:

```
if !searchText.isEmpty {
    arrayFilterEmployed = listEmployed?.filter({$0.text.range(of: searchText, options: [.caseInsensitive, .anchored]) != nil})
}
```

`.anchored` means the check will only pass if at the start of the string. If the options also included `.backwards`, then `.anchored` would mean the match must be at the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks very much buddy. I was able to solve my problem. Now search as I wish. Thank you.

Comment: Also, I have another question for you, please.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you can filter data by using the **hasPrefix**. It will filter out the data based on the text you entered in the search bar.

Replace the following line:

```
arrayFilterEmployed = listEmployed?.filter({$0.text.lowercased().range(of: searchText.lowercased(), options: .caseInsensitive) != nil})
```

with (case-sensitive search)

```
arrayFilterEmployed = listEmployed?.filter({$0.text.hasPrefix(searchText) != nil})
```

and replace with the following (case-insensitive search)

```
arrayFilterEmployed = listEmployed?.filter({$0.text.lowercased().hasPrefix(searchText.lowercased()) != nil})
```

Comment: While `lowercased()` might works on most cases, there are at least one singularity: "ß", the German double "s", eszett, which could causes wrong results.

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses everyone. It helped me a lot. I was able to solve my problem.